# Arabic unicode font is not being rendered properly on PDF generated by Prawn Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, prawn

I've been using Prawn Gem to generate a pdf that contains a list of Care Instructions in many languages using Unicode format. However when it comes to Arabic, the Arabic font is being rendered properly on the Rails app(like the image below).
[image]

but when I use Prawn to convert it into a pdf, it generates this output(the text next to AR)
[image]

Also, Arabic is not a language I am familiar with. Can someone please help me out on how to generate the proper text(like on the image) on the PDF?